# Matplotlib: Drawing a multple line graph in a single plot (discrete plot)

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to know if there is a natural way to draw a graph that consists in a group of lines of varying length like this:

```
5  |   x--------x
4  |     x-----x x--x
3  |
2  |           x----x
1  |     x-----x       
0  |_______________________________
      '      '     '     '     '
      10    20    30    40    50
```

Is the only option to do a graph per line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot command can draw a group of lines, your example can be plotted by a long line

```
plot([15,25],[1,1],'k--',[25,35],[2,2],'k--',[15,25,nan,28,35], [4,4,4,4,4],'k--', [12,27],[5,5],'k--')
```

Alternatively, it plots columns of two matrixes, use

```
X = [[15,25,15,28,12],[25,35,25,35,27]]
Y = [[1,2,4,4,5],[1,2,4,4,5]]
plot(X, Y, 'k--*')
```

In both an axis command may be necessary to see all lines

```
axis((5,50,0,6))
```

Comment: I went with the matrix solution that allowed me to separate the data modeling phase from the drawing phase in a nice way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's more convenient to define a function taken the two terminals of given line as parameters.

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def line(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    plt.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], 'k--x')

plt.figure()

line(14, 1, 24, 1)
line(24, 2, 32, 2)
line(14, 4, 24, 4)
line(27, 4, 32, 4)
line(12, 5, 25, 5)

plt.axis([5, 50, 0, 6])
plt.savefig('lines.png')
```

[image: lines.png]

Another way is using [axhline()](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline) to draw horizontal lines.